# Сортировка символов строки

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть строка, сортировать буквы(символы) строки по алфавиту.

Пример:

```
SET @var="acb";
SELECT @var;
SELECT SORT(@var);
```

Вывод:

acb  `@var;`

abc  `SORT(@var);`

Comment: А что такое "набор символов", в SQL любые "наборы" принято хранить по одному элементу в строке и тогда обычный order by отлично все отсортирует

Comment: переменное или значение поля

Comment: пример: `SET @var=СОРТ("авб")`;

Comment: SQL не предназначен для таких операций. в принципе конечно можно, но оно того не стоит. там будет трехэтажный запрос, разворачивающий строку в отдельные буквы, сортирующий и собирающий обратно. лучше бы такие вещи делать не в SQL или возможно пересмотреть подход к задаче, что бы такое было в принципе не нужно

Comment: хотя на счет 3х этажного я конечно погорячился, но оно все равно того imho не стоит

Comment: По моему человек просто хочет отсортировать символы в строке и получить строку, как ответ. Простая функция для этого пишется и все проблемы решены. И вызываться будет как в вопросе, а не трехэтажными запросами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нам потребуется рабочая таблица с порядковыми номерами от 1 до максимальной длины обрабатываемой строки:

```
create table seqnum(X int not null, primary key(X));
insert into seqnum values(1),(2),(3),(4);
insert into seqnum select X+4 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select X+8 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select X+16 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select X+32 from seqnum;
...
```

Сортирующий запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SET @var="acb";
select group_concat(substr(@var,x,1) order by substr(@var,x,1) separator '') 
  from seqnum
 where x<=length(@var);
```

Данный запрос сначала разворачивает входную строку на отдельные символы, по одному в записи, после чего собирает полученную выборку обратно в строку, но уже в заданном порядке.